# Strange behaviour of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Math.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>       // std::vector


using namespace std;

int stepCount, i, x, y, z, j, k, array1Size, array2Size, tester, checker;
int numstring[10] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
int numstringTest[10] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,9 };
int* numbers;
int* differentNumbers;
int* p;
int* otherNumbers;
void stepCounter(int a) {

    // determines the step number of the number
    if (a / 10 == 0)
        stepCount = 1;
    else if (a / 100 == 0)
        stepCount = 2;
    else if (a / 1000 == 0)
        stepCount = 3;
    else if (a / 10000 == 0)
        stepCount = 4;
    else if (a / 100000 == 0)
        stepCount = 5;
    else if (a / 1000000 == 0)
        stepCount = 6;
    else if (a / 10000000 == 0)
        stepCount = 7;
    else if (a / 100000000 == 0)
        stepCount = 8;
    else if (a / 1000000000 == 0)
        stepCount = 9;

}
void stepIndicator(int b) {
    // indicates each step of the number and pass them into array 'number'
    stepCounter(b);
    numbers = new int[stepCount];

    for (i = stepCount; i>0; i--) {
        //
        /*
        x = (round(pow(10,stepCount+1-i)));
        y = (round(pow(10,stepCount-i)));
        z = (round(pow(10,stepCount-i)));
        */
        x = (int)(pow(10, stepCount + 1 - i) + 0.5);
        y = (int)(pow(10, stepCount - i) + 0.5);
        numbers[i - 1] = (b%x - b%y) / y;
    }

}


int sameNumberCheck(int *array, int arraySize) {
    //checks if the array has two or more of same integer inside return 1 if same numbers exist, 0 if not
    for (i = 0; i<arraySize - 1; i++) {
        //
        for (j = i + 1; j<arraySize; j++) {
            //
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                //
                return 1;
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}


void getDifferentNumbers(int* array, int arraySize) {
    //
    k = 0;
    j = 0;
    checker = 0;
    otherNumbers = new int[10 - arraySize]; //exact number of other numbers is 10 - numbers we have
    for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        if ((i>0)&(checker = 0)) {
            k++;
            otherNumbers[k - 1] = i - 1;
        }
        //
        checker = 0;

        for (j = 0; j<arraySize; j++) {
            //
            p = array + j;
            cout << *p << endl; //ilkinde doğru sonra yanlış yapıyor?!
            if (*p = i) {
                checker++;
            }
        }

    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    stepCounter(999999);
    cout << stepCount << endl;

    stepIndicator(826424563);
    for (j = 0; j<9; j++) {
        //
        cout << numbers[j] << endl;
    }
    cout << sameNumberCheck(numstringTest, 10) << " must be 1" << endl;
    cout << sameNumberCheck(numstring, 10) << " must be 0" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    getDifferentNumbers(numstringTest, 10);
    cout << endl;

    cout << endl << otherNumbers[0] << " is the diff number" << endl;


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Hi, my problem is with pointers actually. You will see above, function getDifferentNumbers. It simply does a comparement if in any given array there are repeated numbers(0-9). To do that, I passed a pointer to the function. I simply do the comparement via pointer. However, there is a strange thing here. When I execute, first time it does correct, but secon time it goes completely mad! This is the function:

```
void getDifferentNumbers(int* array, int arraySize) {
    //
    k = 0;
    j = 0;
    checker = 0;
    otherNumbers = new int[10 - arraySize]; //exact number of other numbers is 10 - numbers we have
    for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        if ((i>0)&(checker = 0)) {
            k++;
            otherNumbers[k - 1] = i - 1;
        }
        //
        checker = 0;

        for (j = 0; j<arraySize; j++) {
            //
            p = array + j;
            cout << *p << endl; //ilkinde doğru sonra yanlış yapıyor?!
            if (*p = i) {
                checker++;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

and this is the array I passed into the function:

```
int numstringTest[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,9};
```

it should give the number 7 in otherNumbers[0], however it does not. And I do not know why. I really can not see any wrong statement or operation here. When I execute, it first outputs the correct values of

```
numstringTest: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,9
```

but on next 9 iteration of for loop it outputs:

```
000000000011111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888
```

Comment: Consider using indentation less than 16000 columns per level, at least when posting here (the webpage style constrains width, plus not everyone's monitor is the same size)

Comment: Can you do something with the formatting of the code - so that it is easier to read on this web page

Comment: My apologies, It wont happen again. Thanks.

Comment: Why not read up about the various containers in the standard library and the use of smart pointers

Comment: If I'd get a buck for every time I'm saying this: Don't use raw pointers or raw arrays, there are [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) and [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some basic problems in your code.

There are multiple comparisons that are not really comparisons, they're assignments. See the following:

```
if((i>0) & (checker=0)){
```

and

```
if(*p = i){
```

In both cases you're assigning values to the variables, not comparing them. An equality comparison should use `==`, not a single `=`. Example:

```
if (checker == 0) {
```

Besides that, you're using `&` (bitwise AND) instead of `&&` (logical AND), which are completely different things. You most likely want `&&` in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I've just noticed this:

```
getDifferentNumbers(numstringTest, 10);
```

and in that function:

```
otherNumbers = new int[10 - arraySize];
```

which doesn't seem right.